# How to reuse the angular layout for sidemenu,header,content and footer

Tags: angular7

I've created the layouts of my angular project but all(side menu, header, footer) are initializing every time when I navigate to any different pages. I did console in constructor to check when the side menu gets called. Then I could see it is printing the console for every navigation.
Due to this, the page flickering happens for all the navigations.After the login success, I will render the core component throughout the session.

I am using the below code structure:

```
  core.component.html:
            <div id="contextWrap">
              <!-- Header -->
              <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
              <!-- Header End -->
              <!--sidebar-->
              <router-outlet name="sidemenu"></router-outlet>
              <!--sidebar end-->

              <!--maincontent-->
              <div class="ui equal width left aligned padded grid stackable">
                <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
              </div>
              <!--maincontent end-->
   <!-- Footer -->
              <router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
   <!-- Footer end-->
            </div>
    app.component.html
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please help me to re-use the angular layouts to avoid page flickering.